# Оператор switch и инициализация переменных

Tags: c++

этот код компилируется

```
 int main() {
        int x = 42;
        switch (x){
            case 1:
                int d = 48;
                break;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

а такой уже нет

```
int main() {
    int x = 42;
    switch (x){
        case 1:
            int d = 48;
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:7:8: error: jump to case label [-fpermissive]
   case 2:
        ^
prog.cpp:5:8: note:   crosses initialization of ‘int d’
    int d = 48;
        ^
```

почему так происходит?

Answer (score 1):

Это происходит из-за того, что компилятор не хочет допустить ситуации, когда вы сможете обратиться к неинициализированной переменной `d`, чтобы избежать ошибки компиляции вы можете ограничить область видимости:

```
 int main() {
    int x = 42;
    switch (x){
        case 1:
            {
            int d = 48;
            break;
            }
        case 2:
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Либо вам нужно объявить эту переменную заранее, тогда никаких ошибок не возникнет и вы сможете работать с ней после `switch`